# Input field loses focus when created dynamically within a table -SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I am creating a input field dynamically in a table based on the data entered  using sap ui5 xml views. The input field doesn't allow user to type continuously. It loses focus after every character is typed. How can I resolve this?

```
<Input value="{newProduct>CustomKeyDisplayLabel}" class="inputfeildclass" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related with the behavior of the input which updates model with every keystroke. and causes a rendering .This is changed in 1.26 version. The value is first checked, updated and modified when the user has finished editing.